NGINX `auth_request` with GeoIP service not populating variables in access log for blocked requests
I'm using NGINX to control access to my website based on the geographic location of the client. Instead of the GeoIP module, I've opted to use an external GeoIP service, as I find it more flexible for my needs. However, I'm facing an issue where the GeoIP-related variables are not being populated in the NGINX access log for requests that are blocked based on their GeoIP country.
Here's the relevant part of my NGINX configuration:
server {
  server_name mydomain.com;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/mydomain.access.log with_geoip;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/mydomain.error.log;

  server_tokens off;
  set_real_ip_from 0.0.0.0/0;
  real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;

  location = @geoip {
    internal;
    proxy_pass http://geoip-service:8080/;
    proxy_set_header X-Geoip-Address $remote_addr;
  }

  location / {
    error_page 403 = @denied;
    auth_request @geoip;

    auth_request_set $geoip_country $upstream_http_x_geoip_country;
    auth_request_set $geoip_stateprov $upstream_http_x_geoip_stateprov;
    auth_request_set $geoip_city $upstream_http_x_geoip_city;
    auth_request_set $geoip_latitude $upstream_http_x_geoip_latitude;
    auth_request_set $geoip_longitude $upstream_http_x_geoip_longitude;
    auth_request_set $geoip_continent $upstream_http_x_geoip_continent;
    auth_request_set $geoip_timezone $upstream_http_x_geoip_timezone;
    auth_request_set $geoip_asn $upstream_http_x_geoip_asn;
    auth_request_set $geoip_asnorganization $upstream_http_x_geoip_asnorganization;

    if ($geoip_country != 'US') {
      return 403;
    }

    proxy_pass http://my-backend;
  }

  location @denied {
    return 403;
  }
}

With the above configuration, the access log correctly logs the GeoIP variables for allowed requests When I make requests that bypass the access control logic, i.e. the following part
if ($geoip_country != 'US') {
  return 403;
}

I've confirmed that the GeoIP service is correctly returning the expected headers by setting up a debug endpoint.
However, when I uncomment this part, the requests are blocked (returning a 403) due to the GeoIP variables are always treated empty. In the logs I can see that are not populated and appear as "-".
[IP_ADDRESS] | - | [2024-04-04T07:55:53+00:00] | "GET / HTTP/1.1" | 403 | 548 | "-" | "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" | "-" | "-" | "-" | "-" | "-" | "-" | "-" | "-" | "-" | "-"

I'm looking for insights or solutions on how to ensure that the GeoIP variables are populated in the access log for all requests, regardless of whether they are allowed or blocked. I prefer not to use the nginx GeoIP module due to its complexity and the specific needs of my setup.
Also, this is my log configuration:
log_format with_geoip '$remote_addr | $remote_user | \[$time_iso8601\] | "$request" | '         '$status | $body_bytes_sent | "$http_referer" | '         '"$http_user_agent" | "$http_x_forwarded_for" | '         '"$geoip_country" | "$geoip_stateprov" | "$geoip_city" | '         '"$geoip_latitude" | "$geoip_longitude" | "$geoip_continent" | '         '"$geoip_timezone" | "$geoip_asn" | "$geoip_asnorganization"';
Since I have a separate nginx for my application which this nginx routes to, I was able to deny allow requests by region by passing geoip header to this inner nginx and changing the inner nginx configuration.
But I need a more clean solution, I want to separate the concerns of these two nginx. Inner is only for routing and outer is only for access management & ssl etc.
Any suggestions or advice would be greatly appreciated!
